# How to distribute a python script across multiple nodes

Tags: python, cluster-computing, distributed

I have some machines available in our office that I want to use to deploy Python scripts to.

My idea was that I have one central machine that manages the deployment of the python scripts and that each node communicates with that central machine to pick up new scripts, etc.

There is no dependency amongst the scripts, they can just run (scrape) and store the results locally.

I am not sure where to start with this.. I have some ideas on writing apps that do this automatically, but I just can not imagine I am the only one trying to do this.

G.

Comment: Egg packages or OS package management come to mind.

Comment: IPython does this sort of thing http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html

Comment: I have been searching myself longer tonight and it seems that Dispy might be what I am looking for. http://dispy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

A Couple things to note. You may not even need to have a management node. I have ran calculations both that had a management node and those that do not. Depending on your cluster, it may honestly be easier to qsub a shell script. There is usually memory in a cluster for this.

Here is a list of other alternatives to IPython, but Peter Sutton's recommendation for IPython is great.

http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a long-term solution (or this can answer can server for people to come), here I have suggestion. I am assuming, you want some solution for not a just one time task, but a long term management (correct me if I get it wrong).

Use a configuration management tool - as per your case a single management node, and merely deploying .py scripts,

I'd recommend using **Ansible**. 
With Anisble you can start with a controller node, making an inventory (list of hosts/machines), and share the controller's public key on all the nodes/machines.

Here's few very plain English blogs to get started with:

- [How to install Ansible](http://devopspy.com/devops/install-ansible-on-centos-7/).
- [Getting started with Ansible](http://devopspy.com/devops/getting-started-ansible/).

---

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of above blog posts.